# How do I install 3d acceleration with an Nvidia Geforce GT520?

Tags: graphics, system

I installed Play on Linux, and it said 3d acceleration wasn't installed so I downloaded an app called 3d acceleration but when I clicked on it it came back XDriInfo returned with non-zero exit code. I use a Nvidea Geforce Gt 520, I've already installed all aditional drivers they offer. Graphix Card seems to be running good as far as that goes, I am new to Ubuntu, and thought using the Play on Linux app would make my windows programs run better. Each time though it says I am missing 3d acceleration, Is that true or just with Play on Linux.

- I have mesa-utils installed and I also installed mesa-utils extra install, still when i click on play on linux it says there doesn't seem to be 3d acceleration we sugest you install and enable it.

Comment: what graphics card and what graphics driver are you using? i.e. `lspci | grep VGA` and the driver installed in Additional Drivers window.  What version of ubuntu are you using?  Please add all replies as an edit into your question.

Comment: First off, What program told you that PlayOnlLinux? or something you installed on PlayOnLinux?, Second What is your graphics card? `lspci | grep VGA` to find out, If you know that then have you installed the proper drivers for it?. add the answers of all that to your question.

Comment: @Paranoid does `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` fix this?

Comment: I have mesa-utils installed and I also installed mesa-utils extra install, still when i click on play on linux it says there doesn't seem to be 3d acceleration we sugest you install and enable it.

Comment: I know theres a linux driver for for geforce Gt 520 at the Nvidea website should I install that too.

Comment: @ParanoidAstronaut: don't use that driver. I've given you the answer below. In fact, that answer is on another question on this site. If my internet was functioning correctly I'd search for it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are lacking some proprietary driver.

To see if such a driver is available for your system, run "Additional Drivers" from the Dash or System menu (I'm going on a limb because you have provided us with no details).

You will be prompted to install any extra drivers you may need.

Answer (score 0):

You need the new Play on Linux:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_oneiric.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```